# Distributed Scheduling Algo MTTMEL simulation in simjava2

Tags: java, eclipse, scheduling, distributed

in my simulation, i have one source(the dispatcher) and 4 receivers. i have made two sinks for two tiers(tier1 and tier2). first 3 receivers are the instance of tier1_sink(with one "in" port and one "out" port) and the last receiver is the instance of tier2_sink(with three "in" ports in0, in1 and in2)
sender is the instance of source with(three "out" i.e. out0,out1 and out2 ports).
i am able to connect sender's out ports to the receiver's in port of tier1 but the i am getting a run time error for linking out port of each receiver in tier1 to the receiver in tier2.
i also tried giving unique port id to each new instance by passing index for that index and then linking as follows:

```
            Sim_system.link_ports("Reciever1", "out"+1, "Receiver4", "in0");
    Sim_system.link_ports("Reciever2", "out"+2, "Receiver4", "in1");
    Sim_system.link_ports("Reciever3", "out"+3, "Receiver4", "in2");
```

but it also didn't work for me.
i know Costas (author of simjava2) is active here.
Please help me out.